# Problem with IF / BEGIN / ELSE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, excel, openrowset

I'm trying to run a select IF there's something inside a folder:

```
   INSERT INTO #tb (SubDirectory, Depth, [File])
   EXEC master..xp_dirtree 'C:\folder\', 10, 1
```

This will populate a table with the name of the file (if there's one inside the folder)

Then, if there's an Excel file there (or not) I will run this query:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM  #listavarejo) > 0 
        SELECT *  FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0','Excel.0;Database=C:\folder\excelfile.xlsx', [Planilha1$])
ELSE
        RAISERROR('NO FILES INSIDE FOLDER.',16,10);
```

The problem is, when I try to run this:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM  #listavarejo) > 0 
        RAISERROR('there are file inside the folder.',16,10);
ELSE
        RAISERROR('theres no files inside the folder.',16,10);
```

It works perfectly. If there's a file inside the folder, the error "there's is a file inside the folder", if there's no files, I can receive the error message after else.

But with the `select * from openrowset`, even with a file inside the folder or not, the query try to runs the select, and obviously I receive the error that the `openrowset` couldn't find the file.

Even using `BEGIN`/`END` I cant fix this.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have an easy way to test this theory right now, but I'd bet that there are some validation checks of the `OPENROWSET` parameters going on when the batch compiles (the whole batch, regardless of `IF` / `ELSE` and whether or not those blocks eventually get executed).

Whenever I encounter this problem, using dynamic SQL is usually a solution.  Give that a shot:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM  #listavarejo) > 0 
        EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT *  FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0'',''Excel.0;Database=C:\folder\excelfile.xlsx'', [Planilha1$])';
ELSE
        RAISERROR('NO FILES INSIDE FOLDER.',16,10);
```

This allows the code inside the dynamic SQL to be compiled only if it's executed.